# Simulink model in a while loop

Tags: matlab, loops, simulink

i want to get values for a simulink model. The aim is to implement the simulink model in a while loop in a matlab script

The simulation has to run 10s. The output of the simulink model is a signal value, which shouldnt exceed the value 1.

The while loop should run, till the right values a,b,c and d are find.

If the simulation is wrong, the value should increment. (a is outer loop and d the inner) All possible combinations should be run.

How it can be implemented, is it possible and how to get with possible errors in the simulink model?

How to get the simulink function data live (If it saved to the workspace, it appears, after the simulation (10s) is done)? I would like to get the results during the run in the workspace.

Have someone experience with it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory.  Do you want all combinations to be run (in which case you don't want a while loop), or do you want it to run until a valid combination is found?

Comment: I want it run until a valid combination is found. For example i have a function y=ax^3+bx^2 + cx +d and the points y(k)=i and y(t) = l with k!=t and i != l. Now i want to find the values a, b, c and d, so the function goes through the points y(k) and y(t) with some deviation (2%)

Comment: @Perilun For any pair of coordinates (k,i) and (t,l) there will be an infinite number of sets of coefficients {a,b,c,d} of y(x) that will pass through the points.

Comment: @KillaKem I know that it could be an infinite number of combinations. The script should stop, if it finds one. It shouldn't find every combinations.

Comment: @Philg Goddard: What do you mean under the asset block? I do not know what an asset block is!

Comment: That should have been `assert` block.

Comment: The problem is, that the assert block is do not running if the signal is null. My aim is that the model should run, if the signal is 0 or in a bandwith between 0.3 and -0.3.

Comment: So... you just have some logic before the `assert` block checking the range.  That certainly doesn't preclude its use.

Comment: That sounds logic, but how i can implement the values in the mask, if the values a,b, c and d are wrong? Can I do this in the simulink or have i do this in a m-script?

Comment: What (block's) mask?

Comment: In real the a, b, c and d are the kp and ki values from the pi-control, i have two of them. My aim is to find the right values of kp and ki in a loop and dont type some values myself. (The autotuning doesnt work)

Comment: As you should be doing in most/all models, you should parameterize your model (i.e. use variable names as the block parameters) and define the value of the variables in the MATLAB Workspace. When you simulate the model, during initialization, it will pick up the values from the Workspace.  It sounds as if you should have MATLAB code that defines the 4 gains (possible in 4 nested loops), then within the innermost loop be using the `sim` function to simulate the model, aggregate outputs, and determine if the condition(s) you need to be met has(have) been met.

Comment: That is my aim. The problem is i dont understand how to define a constant value in simulink from the m-file. I just found that it should be a matrix with two columns (time and value). But the value should be constant during the simulation. So is it possible to set a constant value, without the declaration as matrix or vector?

Comment: Yes, you use a `Constant` block, and put the name of your variable in the block.